# Masterpage in asp.net CSS

Tags: c#, css, master-pages

```
My masterpage code:
<head runat="server">
<title>System</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style>
.masterfixed { table-layout:fixed; color:rebeccapurple}
.masterfixed td { overflow: hidden;}
</style>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="bootstrap/css/masdesign.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

I only want my colour on my masterpage. But why does this apply to all my font in my contentplaceholder. Please help thanks.

Comment: post your `<body>` code here

Answer (score 0):

You could put your `contentplaceholder` in a div and give the div the CSS class or the style you want:

```
<div style="font:bold 12px arial;color:#000000">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

If it does not work, try it with a `!important` at the end of each style:
`sytle="color:#000000 !important"`

This makes sure that the div uses this style and not a style defined in a CSS class.